# How do I configure a value sequence on an existing table?

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table that serves as a queue to an external process. The application needs to allow reordering of the queue. I am building an asp.net core app that uses EF Core for interfacing with the sql database. I am using the code first approach. I have added a field named QueueOrder. I have considered various approaches and nothing seems to be working for this use case.

One approach is to default the QueueOrder field to be the same as the Id field. The Id is an integer sequence that increments by 1 for each inserted row, so that should serve fine as a starting point for the Queue Order. Then as the user reorders, I can update that field by swapping QueueOrder values.

What's the best way to achieve this with Entity Framework Code First? I have read through the Default Values, Generated Values, Alternate Keys, and Sequences docs and nothing seems to fit my use case. EF won't allow me to add a sequence beause the table already exists. I tried to use a Default Value but you can't use column names in that. You can only use constants and constant expressions.

I cannot use an alternate key because EF won't allow me to modify keys. Apparently I can designate the field as a GeneratedValue and then use a trigger, but, I don't see any way to specify the trigger with code first.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<JobQueue>(b =>
{
    b.Property(j => j.QueueOrder)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("Id"); //This fails
});
```

Is there a code first supported approach to this?

Comment: Sequence sounds good to me, since it's not associated with any table. How exactly EF Core does not allow you to add sequence? e.g. exception - what, where?

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the documentation on sequences. I thought that I needed to use the table name in the HasSequence() method signature.

Comment: Okay, sequence has worked out.